# How to check if duplicate meta title present for category in Magento2

Tags: magento2, category, collection

I am generating a report for the categories with duplicate Meta titles.

I have loaded all the categories and checking conditions one by one like below with the direct MySQL queries.

```
$connection = $this->_resource->getConnection(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
$categoryId = 4;// current categoryID
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$category = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($categoryId);
$metaTitle = $category->getMetaTitle();
$query = "SELECT value FROM catalog_category_entity_varchar WHERE attribute_id='49' AND entity_id <> '".$categoryId."' and AND VALUE='".$metaTitle."'" ;
$Result = $connection->query($query);
$resultData = $Result->fetchAll();
if(count($resultData) > 0{
    $error = "Duplicate present";
}else{
    $error = "No Duplicate";
}
```

The above code working fine, but I like to modify the code by the standard. Is there any way to load category collection with filter and check the condition like above.

I am checking if the duplicate meta title presents apart from the selected category, needs to show the message.

Please, someone, suggest me how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this below code in your file :

```
protected $_storeManager;
protected $catCollFactory;
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $catCollFactory,
    ...
) {
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->catCollFactory = $catCollFactory;
}


public function yourFunction(){
    $categoryFactory = $this->catCollFactory->create();
    $categories = $categoryFactory
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->setStore($this->_storeManager->getStore());
    $catMetaTitleArr = [];
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        if(in_array($category->getMetaTitle(), $catMetaTitleArr))
        {
            echo $category->getId(). "has duplicate meta title found";
        } else {
            $catMetaTitleArr[] = $category->getMetaTitle();
        }
    }
}
```

Remove generated and clean cache.

Comment: hello @Rohan. Thanks got it now.